# Как избавиться от глобальных переменных при функциональном программировании?

Tags: функциональное-программирование

Я недавно начал интересоваться функциональным программированием и решил применить этот подход в своем проекте. Но столкнулся с тем, что не до конца понимаю, как реализовать некоторые вещи в ФП.

Например, есть часть кода, которая создает и заполняет базу данных содержимым csv файла. Так как в нем шапка может встречаться несколько раз, то возникает потребность постоянно помнить текущую шапку, и сравнивать с новой встреченой, и в определенный момент заменять текущую ею. Но хранение глобальных значений и их изменение не есть функциональных подход. Постоянно делать запрос в БД что бы узнать шапку мне кажется не целесообразным. Таскать за собой значение текущей шапки из функции к функции в качестве аргумента, так же не вариант, так как многие функции должны отслеживать это значение. Поэтому, хотелось бы понять как организовывать алгоритм в таком случае, что бы он придерживался функциональной парадигмы.Я понимаю что вопрос очень не конкретный, но без понимания такой маленькой детали, не получается правильно спроектировать программу.

Comment: Обычно в учебниках по ФП расписаны примеры довольно примитивных вычислительных задач. Но когда дело доходит до большой программы, сложной обработки данных, GUI не просто понять как придерживаться ФП во многих случаях , когда привык мыслить императивно.

Comment: Для начала не надо императивно детализировать задачу. "Помнить текущую шапку, сравнивать с новой встреченной и заменять текущую ею" -- как раз пример такой детализации. В ФП такая задача формулируется совсем по другому. Мы говорим, что CSV состоит из , скажем, "секций", которые состоят из "шапки" и "строк", где "шапка" и "строки" это список "текстовых полей". Для такой структуры удобно написать  функции, начиная с "обработать CSV", вызывающую "обработать секцию", которая, в свою очередь, вызовет "обработать шапку" и "обработать строки". "Шапка" станет локальной переменной в "обработать секцию"

Comment: @Mark Shevchenko , Но ведь файл проходится построчно (файл довольно большой ля того, что бы читать его целиком в список), и как то нужно узнать о том ,  что очередная строка похожа на шапку, но отлична от текущей в таблице, в таком случае нужно создать новую таблицу с этой шапкой. Ведь все равно требуется доступ к этому значению в процессе обработки csv файла.

Comment: Вы не переживайте, что файл слишком большой. Прочитайте весь и обработайте. Потом перепишете на Хаскеле, где можно ввод-выход спрятать за монадой `IO`. Решать проблемы по одной лучше всего: если хотите разобраться с ФП, разбирайтесь. Когда начнёте понимать, сможете оптимизировать. Сейчас бессмысленно.